# Suggested Edit Reviews on Deleted Questions

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, deleted-questions

Just been doing some edit reviews, and came accross [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10690394) which I thought I'd take a closer look at the question.

It turned out that the question was deleted, and after completing the review (just in case it wasn't actually deleted) I had a look at my history and found my previous edit review was on a deleted question as well.

I would have thought that edit reviews on deleted questions were a pointless exercise, and those reviews would have been halted when the question was deleted.

Is this a bug, a caching issue perhaps. If it isn't a bug, is there a reason for allowing edit reviews to continue?

---

Two others reviewed the edit up to an hour after I did. Surely the cache isn't that long!

Comment: Wonder why they deleted it.  It's got enough components there for someone to answer it, at least.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @KevinGuan: Can I blame caching for that website's terrible kerning?

Comment: @Kevin I refer you to the previous answer.

Comment: @worldofjr: Well, seems you missed the the tip there which says: *Advice may be invalid due to caching*.

Comment: @worldofjr: Which answer of mine?

Comment: @KevinGuan I was refering Kevin (the other one) to your comment since he was asking if he could blame caching for something.

Comment: @worldofjr: Okay understand :P

Comment: Well, questions can be edited while they’re deleted and then later potentially undeleted, if the question turns out to be valuable enough. I’m not familiar with the exact process, though.

Comment: @Xufox Since <2k users can't see deleted questions, it doesn't make much sense them having edits accepted on them ... or does it?

Comment: @worldofjr In this case the edit was probably suggested before the question got deleted.

Comment: Perhaps deletion should auto-reject pending edits?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bug?

Deleted questions (and answers) can be edited by others, so that's by design.

> a pointless exercise

Probably yes, most of the time. Sometimes posts are deleted by owners if they want to improve it after posting without getting unwanted attention (downvotes/comments). If there's reason to assume this is happening it *might* be useful to do minor edits, although you'll probably interfere with the OP's editing efforts.

Another effect of editing posts is that it educates users in how to format/layout a post. If, for example, we significantly improve a code block's indentation in a deleted question, this might prompt the OP to do a better job in a subsequent question. I wouldn't count on it though.